# No ealier segments error. Gazebo 1.3

Tags: gazebo-sensor, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am implementing gazebo-1.3 ros-plugin for PR2.

Now, PR2 moves well, but my contact sensor plugin does not countinuously give collision-rostopic like collision-gztopic.

I found following error message from terminal.

```
[ERROR] [1358114072.409449185]: No ealier segments. First segment starts at 27.536 (now=27.534)
```

I could not find which plugin gives this error, but after appearing this message, my contact plugin does not publish any topics.

Is there anybody knows the meaning of this error message?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/774/no-ealier-segments-error.-gazebo-1.3/) by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I figured out.

The problem is that gazebo and ROS does not have syncronized time.

I published gazebo's simulation time into ROS as '/clock'.

And I set ROS parameter 'use_sim_time' into true.

There is no more error and finally PR2 works with ROS and Gazebo-1.3.

It is worth to read: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock

---

Originally posted by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) with karma: 47 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0